# RLLib EpiesodeV2 missing method to query latest dict returned from step?

Tags: ray, rllib

The [Episode class](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/8f3ca4b87457ebfadd14b3c897e79a849e1ae368/rllib/evaluation/episode.py) provided the method last_info_for to pull the info dict return to the agent at the latest step. Now [EpisodeV2](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/8f3ca4b87457ebfadd14b3c897e79a849e1ae368/rllib/evaluation/episode_v2.py) doesn't have such a method, and subsequently returns errors like `'EpisodeV2' object has no attribute 'last_info_for'`.

Is there a recommended workaround for this?